# Plotly express color bar argument missing go.Bar

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-dash

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x=“sepal_width”, y=“sepal_length”, color=“species”)
fig.show()
```

If I want to write the same code in plotly.graph_objects , than how I can include the color argument without using for loop. Basically I want to use bar and line chart in same axis with bar having a color code based on a different variable and pass that as a return in Dash.

```
bars = 
for label, label_df in df.groupby(‘label’):
bars.append(go.Bar(x=label_df.x, y=label_df.y, name=label, marker={‘color’: colors[label]}))
trace1 = bars

trace2 = go.Scatter(x=label_df.x, y=label_df.y, name=‘Nifty 50’, mode=‘lines+markers’)
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1])

fig.show()
```

Comment: You can use this `fig` directly in Dash actually, no need to rewrite anything with `graph_objects`...

Comment: SO I want to build multiple traces and pass def update_figure(client_picker_name):
   df_new = df[df.Client_Type == client_picker_name]

   trace1 = go.Bar(x=df_new.Date, y=df_new.abc)
   trace2 = go.Bar(x=df_new.Date, y=df_new.xyz)

   return {
        'data' : [trace1,trace2]
     }

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

Update:

```
df = px.data.iris()
trace1 = [go.Scatter(x=label_df.sepal_width, 
                     y=label_df.sepal_length, 
                     name=label,
                     mode='markers') 
          for label, label_df in df.groupby('species')]
fig = go.Figure(data=trace1)
```

Comment: trace1 = [go.Bar(x=label_df.x,  y=label_df.y,  name=label,  marker={‘color’: colors[label]})
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier. I tried and its throwing an error